# When finding the derivative of the integral of a function I get different results

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I am using wolframalpha.com and other online calculus calculators.
The problem I am solving:

$$\int x\cos^2\left(x^2\right)dx$$

But the integral and its derivative don't match. Am I doing something wrong? What am I typing in wrong? I think it is something as simple as a mistype but I cannot see where.

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a general tip, if you get two answers for the same trigonometric / hyperbolic problem that look a bit different, the first thing to check for is if you can use identities to get the answers to look a bit more familiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infact the derivative of the integral is just the same as $x\cos^2(x^2)$. You just have to use the identity:
$$\cos 2x +1= 2\cos^2x$$
Replacing $x$ by $x^2$, we have$$\cos(2x^2)+1=2\cos^2(x^2)$$
Hence we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac12x(\cos (2x^2)+1)&=\frac12x(2\cos^2(x^2))\\
&=x\cos^2(x^2)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

If we have:

$$\int f(x) dx= g(x)$$
and
$$\int f(x) dx = h(x)$$

This implies that $g(x)=h(x)+C$ for every $x$.

Therefore, especially in the integrals of trigonometric functions, it is very common to achieve two seemingly different integrals of the same function, but it's *usually* quite simple to show equivalence.

In this case, as Faiq's answer points out, the two expressions are identical.